# RoundingMode.HALF_UP does not give correct result

Tags: java, jdk6

I used code snippet below using RoundingMode.HALF_UP:

```
        Double value = new Double( "18.74");

        Double result = (value*75)/100;
        System.out.println("Result: "+result);

        BigDecimal roundedValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(result).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        System.out.println("Rounded Value: "+roundedValue);
```

It gave me the result below:

```
Result: 14.054999999999998
Rounded Value: 14.05
```

But the expected value should be `14.06`
How fix the issue?Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Is it? You round half up on scale 2 - so basically you are rounding 14.054 up to 14.05?

Comment: Do your whole calculation with BigDecimal, don’t start with a double. That way you’ll riund 14.055 to 14.06 correctst

Comment: Indeed, you can already see that the problem occurs before rounding - you're starting with 14.054999999999998 when presumably you expected to start with 14.055. The rounding is behaving exactly correctly with that input.

Comment: If you start with `new BigDecimal("18.74").multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(75))           .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100))` you'll get the answer you expect.

Comment: Thanks @Erwin Bolwidt, it works when using BigDecimal.

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeet , it works when using BigDecimal